# add a string to a constant in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code as shown below which prints the following o/p on console.

`React Code:`

```
if(type === "/page/chapter") {
    console.log(trailFR);  // Line A
}
```

**Line A** prints the following o/p on console:

```
/a2-fr
/a1-fr
/world-2020
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the react code above so that it prints the following output:

```
/chapters/a2-fr
/chapters/a1-fr
/chapters/world-2020
```

This is what I have tried but I am not getting the expecting output:

```
if(type === "/page/chapter") {
    trailFR = {"/chapters"+trailFR}
    console.log(trailFR);  // Line A
}
```

Comment: `\`/chapters/${trailFR}\``

Comment: like this trailFR=``/chapters/${trailFR}``  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways

[Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
console.log(`/chapters${trailFR}`)
```

or using String concatenation

```
console.log('/chapters'+trailFR)
```

or using [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) method of a string

```
console.log('/chapters'.concat(trailFR.toString()))
```

Comment: I tried with all your possible solutions trailFR=`/chapters${trailFR}` OR

trailFR='/chapters'+trailFR OR

trailFR='/chapters'.concat(trailFR.toString()) but it didn't work. The error message which I am getting is `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: @flash Your are getting this error because you are trying to assign it to `trailFR` and it's a constant